# Programme is giving me segmentation error, no clue why

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to program with C and implementing a function which calculates the days of the current year by entering the date. However, it keeps giving me a segmentation error. Can anyone help out?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int datum2int(int day, int month){
  int result=0;
  int array[]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30};

  while((month-1)!=0){
    result += array[month-2];
    month--;
  }

  result +=day;
  return result;
}


int main(){
  int day,month;    
  scanf("%d, %d",&day, &month);
  printf("%d", datum2int(day, month));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: no, because when month is 1 the while loop wont start

Comment: Did you debug the code?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the code and question is very unclear about is `january` month 0 or month 1

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. (in the current scenario, the returned value should be 2)

Comment: before calling `scanf()`, should prompt the user, so the user knows what is expected for input.

Comment: after calling `scanf()` should check the month value and the day value to assure they are in range and that the day value is appropriate for the month

Comment: should have the user also enter the year, as that makes a difference for the number of days in the month of february

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get seg fault because of the `,` between the `%d`.

Remove it

`scanf("%d %d",&day, &month);`

Comment: Still your program would crash if month is not within legible range.

Comment: @hmatar yes...op needs to check in function

Comment: Agreed, but the main issue was constant seg fault.

Comment: There is nothing stopping the user from entering `1,2` which would be acceptable to the OPs posted code.

Comment: The presence (or lack there of) of a comma being entered by the user is a 'strawman' argument.  1) the code should have prompted the user with an appropriate statement, 2) the code should have checked the returned value from `scanf()` to assure that the statement was successful. (in this scenario, the returned value should be 2)

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault is happening here: `result += array[month-2];`

Two reasons can cause segmentation fault in your case

1. `month` is less than 1: your will enter the loop and index for `array` will be less than 0.
2. `month` is larger than 12: in this case index in `array` is greater than 11.

Solution: in your main function you need to check if month is within the range.

Comment: Because thats not really what the problem was about.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I did not notice the comma. :)

Comment: actually, this IS the root of the problem.   Amongst other things, the data array should have a 0 for the first entry  (and no need for the current final entry.) and the final entry is not correct, as December has 31 days (and November only has 30 days, so the data array is not correct.